# Approximating arithmetic values in python

Tags: python, rounding

```
print((2.15-2)*60)
```

The output comes as 8.999999999999995. How can I get 9 as the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function:

> Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest **integer** to its input.

```
print(round((2.15-2)*60))
```